# R - Markdown avoiding package loading messages

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I have been using Knitr via R-Studio, and think it is pretty neat. I have a minor issue though. When I source a file in an R-Chunk, the knitr output includes external comments as follows:

```
+ FALSE Loading required package: ggplot2
+ FALSE Loading required package: gridExtra
+ FALSE Loading required package: grid
+ FALSE Loading required package: VGAM
+ FALSE Loading required package: splines
+ FALSE Loading required package: stats4
+ FALSE Attaching package: 'VGAM'
+ FALSE The following object(s) are masked from 'package:stats4':
```

I have tried to set R-chunk options in various ways but still didn't seem to avoid the problem:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, results=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=FALSE, warning=FALSE} 
source("C:/Rscripts/source.R");

```
````

Is there any way to comment out these messages?

Comment: set `options(warn=-1)` and back to `options(warn=0)` at the end of the Rmd. Takes care of all startup package messages. Note that you'd be turning off warnings, but only while the Rmd is being rendered.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

You can use `include=FALSE` to exclude everything in a chunk.

````
```{r include=FALSE}
source("C:/Rscripts/source.R")
```
````

If you only want to suppress messages, use `message=FALSE` instead:

````
```{r message=FALSE}
source("C:/Rscripts/source.R")
```
````

Comment: The fact that `results` can't be `FALSE` is unfortunate.  I would rather the chunk option `results` be split into `results`, `hold`, and `markup` which would all be boolean values.  Alas, this is not how it works.

Comment: what if we want to turn off messages globally for ALL chunks, how do you do that?

Comment: @PrasadChalasani `knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE)` http://yihui.name/knitr/options/

Comment: @Head `results` can be `FALSE` (which is an alias of `results="hide"`) since **knitr** 1.16: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1360

Answer (score 121):

````
```{r results='hide', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(RJSONIO)
library(AnotherPackage)
```
````

see [Chunk Options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) in the Knitr docs

Comment: The `warning=FALSE` is the only thing that worked for me. Definitely the best way to include the chunk in your output without the ugly warnings!

Comment: How to set this for the entire document?. Do i have to put it into each chunk manually?.

Comment: @Misaki See Yihui's comment above regarding knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE)

Comment: When i put this format on top of my script i got `unexpected symbol in "{r results"`

Comment: Yeah I tend to do the same, a chunk just to load libraries, in R chunk like `{r global, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}`

Answer (score 7):

My best solution on R Markdown was to create a code chunk only to load libraries and exclude everything in the chunk.

```
{r results='asis', echo=FALSE, include=FALSE,}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning=FALSE)
#formating tables
library(xtable)

#data wrangling
library(dplyr)

#text processing
library(stringi)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but here's another way to do it.

You can modify the R code itself instead of the chunk options, by wrapping the `source` call in `suppressPackageStartupMessages()`, `suppressMessages()`, and/or `suppressWarnings()`. E.g:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(suppressPackageStartupMessages({
source("C:/Rscripts/source.R")
})
```
````

You can also put those functions around your `library()` calls inside the `"source.R"` script.