# Remove message from Zelig package loading when swearing/kniting

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I'm using `sweave` and my r chunk uses the package `Zelig`, which produces a message every time it loads. I've tried everything from `message=FALSE`, `warnings=F`, `comment=F`, as well as `suppressMessages(library(Zelig))`. Nothing works! any ideas?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090838/r-markdown-avoiding-package-loading-messages)?

Comment: yes, hence my statement "I've tried everything from....

Comment: I've also tried suppressPackageStartupMessages to no avail

Comment: Does `everything` include `include = FALSE`? (Cannot test it at the moment because a dependency of `Zelig` is not yet available for R3.2.4).

Comment: include=F does not work either

Comment: I also tried invisible(library(Zelig)) -doesnt work...

Comment: Which package and R version are you using? I don't get any startup message using Zelig 5.0-9 and R3.2.4.

Comment: I'm using 3.2.2 but on my other computer i have 3.2.4 and Zelig doesn't load bc of a dependency problem related the graphs package (I asked others to check on their systems to verify it wasn't unique to my computer and they all faced the same problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so my work around is to load the Zelig library in a separate chunk than the rest of my code and to use `results=hide` like in the following example:

```
    TEXT
    <<results=hide, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
    library(Zelig) 
    @
    TEXT
    <<>>=
    CODE
    @
```

Comment: Does it produce the same message with `require()` instead of `library()`?

Comment: `require()` and `library()` produce the same results