# Suppress message of the tm_shape() function (from tmap library)

Tags: r, rgdal, r-sf, tmap

In RStudio I try to knit my code which produces a map into html-file and get in compiled html-file besides a map an undesired message:

> "**## Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3**".

This message is produced by the function `tm_shape()` which plots a map from `tmap` library.

I tried to surround construction with `tm_shape()` function by the construction `invisible(capture.output(...))`. It doesn't work.

I also tried to execute the function `tmap_options(show.messages = FALSE)` before calling `tm_shape()`. It doesn't work.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rgdal))

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tmap))

tmap_options(show.messages = FALSE)

invisible(capture.output(area = readOGR("adm1.shp")))

area@data$VARNAME_1 = as.character(area@data$VARNAME_1)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

area@data = left_join(area@data, df, by = c("VARNAME_1" = "Area"))

tm_shape(area) + tm_fill("x", style = "fixed", palette = "Greens", breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50), labels = c("0-10", "10-20", "20-30", "30-40", "40-50")) + tm_legend(text.size = 1) + tm_layout(legend.position = c("left", "bottom")) + tm_borders("grey") + tm_layout(frame = F)
```

**So, the question is how to suppress this undesired message?**

[image]

Comment: Did you try `suppressMessages` and `suppressWarnings`

Comment: `options(warn=-1)` maybe?(Not always recommended).

Comment: The message is more likely to arise because you did `library(sf)`. Add `message=FALSE` in the chunk options.

Comment: Yes, I tried to surround construction with tm_shape() both with suppressMessages and suppressWarnings - it doesn't work.options(warn=-1) also doesn't work.

Comment: I don't call sf library. Probably tmap library loads sf library automatically. "message=FALSE" works! Problem solved. Thank you Sébastien!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - Markdown avoiding package loading messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090838/r-markdown-avoiding-package-loading-messages). Also check [R for Data Science - Chunk options](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/r-markdown.html#chunk-options)