# In R programming, warn.conflicts doesn't work to hide the warning messages. How to fix this issue? (R version is 3.5.2)

Tags: r

I have used `library(readxl,warn.conflicts = F)` in my R-markdown file but the warning messages are still displayed in my knitted file. Same is the case when the code is executed in R program.

Tried `library(readxl,warn.conflicts = F)` code but the warnings are displayed.

```
library(readxl,warn.conflicts = F) #Warnings are displayed
library(dplyr,warn.conflicts = F) #Warnings are displayed
library(tidyverse,warn.conflicts = T) #Warnings are displayed
```

To hide the warning and other messages while we load the library. In R-Markdown/R code output, I would like to display the library name but without any warning messages.

Comment: `suppressMessages(library(readxl))` or something like that?

Comment: You have to set the options on the code chunk. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090838/r-markdown-avoiding-package-loading-messages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - Markdown avoiding package loading messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090838/r-markdown-avoiding-package-loading-messages)

Comment: You also need to set `conflicts.policy`, read more in `help(library)`.